# android:layout_marginLeft doesn't work in API 8

Tags: android, android-layout

android:layout_marginLeft works fine on 4.4.2 but it doesn't work on 2.2.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Here is row_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/authorImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poemNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Çanakkale Şehitlerine"
            android:textColor="@color/author_list_textcolor_selector"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put the margin on the `LinearLayout`. You can also try to use a padding on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: But why doesn't it work? What is the problem?

Comment: It's difficult to say, as I can't really test it right now, but generally try to put margins and paddings as far up as possible in your view hierarchy and sometimes margings don't work for various reasons. In such a case try using a padding instead.

Comment: In your case most likely the behavior of margins in a `LinearLayout` with weights changed at some point above API 8.

Comment: @XaverKapeller thank you, your suggestion worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. In this case I will shortly write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the margin on the `LinearLayout` containing the `TextView` instead of on the `TextView` itself. If this doesn't work you can also try to apply a padding to the `LinearLayout`.

Essentially try this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/authorImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poemNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Çanakkale Şehitlerine"
            android:textColor="@color/author_list_textcolor_selector"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your case most likely the behaviour of margins in a `LinearLayout` with weights changed at some point above API 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you for more improvement of your code to show list item.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/authorImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poemNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Çanakkale Şehitlerine"
            android:textColor="@color/author_list_textcolor_selector"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```